# Wordpress issue - Why does my search title have duplicate content?

Tags: wordpress

Apologies, I'm new here, so hopefully, I explain this well. I have an issue with Wordpress mobile where it's incorrectly displaying two different texts for the search title text. This is only on mobile, and it's only on our Wordpress pages.

I don't have a reputation to post the image, but here's the gist. You type in Google mobile pros and cons of bankruptcy, and ours shows up with the search title text: "Pros and Cons of Bankruptcy - Company | Blog - Company"

I like the Company | Blog as that's what we have in our settings, but I have no idea where the second "- Company" is coming from.

Any idea what's going on? Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you checked in Wordpress Backend under "Settings -> General"? Are you using any seo plugins or do overwrite the page title in some way?

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write!! We have what we want as the Site Title, so that is correct. That might be it. We just got some plugins to help us optimize speed from here: https://www.sparringmind.com/speed-up-wordpress/, but I almost think this was happening before it! So weird!